# jQuery UI autocomplete issue on SharePoint 2013

Tags: jquery-ui

I've been working on a project and I decided to use jQuery-UI Autocomplete, the problem I've encountered is that when I scroll the page the "Dropdown menu" doesn't stay attached to his original position, it stays in the same position without moving whit the page and the textbox as expected (hope i've explained myself in a proper way). This problem seems to appear only in Sharepoint as in JSfiddle it doesn't act like that. Any idea why? Thanks a lot.

```
$("#"+tIDle).autocomplete({
     source: valuesA,
     minLength: 0,
}).focus(function() {
     $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

[JSBin Sample](http://output.jsbin.com/otozo4)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue you are facing is already solved by jQuery UI team.

This has been fixed with the addition of the `appendTo` option for the `autocomplete` method.

Take a look at this question: [jQuery Autocomplete box stays open and in same position when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138485/jquery-autocomplete-box-stays-open-and-in-same-positoin-when-scrolling)

Bug reported on jQuery UI Autocomplete: [Autocomplete doesn't work well inside fixed position divs](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8391)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked at the two links that you have posted but I already knew it. I had also already tried to use the option appendTo, but has not changed anything.

Do you know something else that can help me with this issue?